Need help identifying TV show with Hiroshima/Nagasaki survivor
I once saw a youtube clip of a 1950s/60s american TV show that had a japanese man on (i want to say in his 40s or so).  The host/show brought in many influential people from the Japanese man's life; it was kind of like a biography TV show.  
The most poignant part I remember was the pilot of the plane that dropped one of the atom bombs came on the show and shook the man's hand, but the American pilot was visibly shaken.  I just can't remember the name of the TV show.  Any articles with background on the event would be awesome too; I want to say I once read one detailing how the pilot almost missed the show, after drinking or something.

The show was "This is Your Life." The "pilot" was the Enola Gay copilot Robert Lewis
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_Your_Life

One of the show's subjects was Rev. Kiyoshi Tanimoto, a survivor of
  the atomic bombing of Hiroshima. During the episode Edwards introduced
  Tanimoto to Robert A. Lewis, the co-pilot of the Enola Gay, the plane
  that dropped the bomb on Hiroshima.[5]





this is absolutely it! Thanks.
